# Не работает проверка строки на соответствие

Tags: python, строки

Не могу разобраться, почему сравнение не проходит успешно.

При этом оператор `in` вместо `==` срабатывает, но он не подходит, так как можно ввести просто `@mail.ru'` и вхождение будет засчитано.

mails.txt - текстовый документ со списком мейлов, каждый с новой строки.
message.text - переменная ввода пользователя

```
passwords = open('/root/mails.txt', encoding='utf-8').readlines()
for line in passwords:
    if message.text.lower() == line:
        msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Спасибо! Напишите что-нибудь в чат для начала работы.")
        bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, answer)
        break    
else:
  
     bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Извините, данный емейл не найден. Попробуйте снова или обратитесь в поддержку.")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Может проблема в том, что в одной из сравниваемых строк есть лишние пробелы в начале или конце строки?
`if message.text.lower() == line:` заменить на `if message.text.lower().strip() == line.lower().strip():`

Comment: СПАСИБО! Заработало!